# Execute a Function when Another Application sets an Event

Tags: c#, events

I need to execute a Task in one application when Second application done with Some processing. For that I am using Events.

I created events in each application with Same name. By Name, I mean Parameter which is passed while creating event.
Code looks like this in BOTH applications:

```
 using System.Threading;

EventWaitHandle Multi_App = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "Process_Done");
```

After Processing, Application "A" sets this Event by calling

```
Multi_App.Set()
```

I want that Application "B" should sense that this event is Set and Execute a specific function,say `App_A_Done()`. Till then it will do some other task.

One option for me was to create a thread and in that thread I would be waiting for the event by

```
Multi_App.WaitOne();
```

Whenever it will get the event, Function `App_A_Done` is called manually.

A friend told methat I "Subscribe" to this event and this function will be executed automatically whenever event is set. So no need of thread and all.

I tried but couldn't figure out how to subscribe to such events.

[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) MSDN article says I can write

```
publisher.RaiseCustomEvent += new CustomEventHandler(HandleCustomEvent);
```

But How can I apply this to my case coz `Mutli_App.Set += new....` gives me Error.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You are confusing terms and terminology. A C# [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) has nothing to do with the [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.aspx) object. Furthermore, if you're actually talking about two separate applications or processes, you cannot transfer objects between them unless you use very specific channels. I suggest you completely rewrite this question because as it is, it makes little sense.

Comment: Ohh...Thanks for Suggestion... Now I need to check for other means of Communication between two applications (But this thing works :) I will wait for others to add there suggestions, otherwise will close this question.